# How to set a separate proxy for Wagtail to fetch YouTube embed video?

Tags: django, wagtail

I tried to add a YouTube video in article content, but it alway failed to upload the video link because YouTube is blocked in my country. So I built a HTTP proxy to watch YouTube, how could I tell the wagtail application to use my HTTP proxy while fetching YouTube embed metadata?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your server and your users are behind a firewall that blocks access to YouTube. So there is two problems to solve:

1. Your Wagtail app should be able to access https://www.youtube.com/oembed to fetch metadata and `iframe` code to embed (see [the example response](https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DM3r2XDceM6A&format=json)).
2. Your users should be able to access youtube servers to watch videos.

To solve the first problem you can use a custom embed finder. You can find some information on [how to add a custom embed finder](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/advanced_topics/settings.html?#embeds) the Wagtail's documentation.

Your embed finder should recognise youtube urls and send requests to fetch meta info through the proxy.

The second problem should be solved on the client's side (the client's browser should use proxy) or you should transparently proxy traffic youtube <-> your users somehow. It's not really Wagtail related issue, so I'll leave it with you.